# Iterate through a list of objects and point to the node that matches a certain criteria

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, iterator

I am using a custom data structure 'block' and have stored several blocks in a list:

```
 list openList<block>
```

I now need to iterate through each block, access the data member 'f' (an integer) and check which has the lowest f cost.

My logic would be to simply have a pointer pointing to the best block value, rather than each time copying the best blocks values.

Here's my code:

```
for (std::list<block>::iterator openi = openList.begin(); openi != openList.end();  openi++){
        if ((*openi).f < bestFCost){
            bestFCost = (*openi).f;
            // Here's where I need help....
        }
    }
```

I don't think what I'm asking of the iterator is possible. I wish to set

```
 block * Q
```

To the data the iterator points to, but I need the entire object not the data members.

Edit:
Very simple solution! I initilised Q with a typo (Q* instead of *Q)!

block * Q = 0;

Then in the part of the loop I commented:

```
 Q = &(*openi)
```

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*openi` is of type `block`, right? So you can simply take the address of that:

```
block * Q = &*openi;
```

The `&*` might seem redundant, but the `*` is an operator on the iterator, returning a `block` type, as opposed to scenario's where `*` is a dereference, and the `&` references it again.

Or you can store the iterator itself:

```
std::list<block>::iterator Q = openi;
```

Or you can store the object by value, assuming you implemented the copy constructor:

```
block Q = *openi;
```

Comment: Ouch!! A typo on my end, I set block Q * = &(*openi); !! Wondered why it wouldn't work! Thanks buddy!